# Threadpool using upto 200 threads

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, threadpool

i have this code which i run with queued 10,000, even when a max of 50 is set but the threadpool counts goes to high.

can anyone help me fish out the fault

```
Public Sub DoWork(ByVal objItem As Object)
        Dim objUrl as String = DirectCast(objItem, string)
        Try
            If objUrl Is Nothing Then
                exit sub
            End If

            Dim URL as New Uri(objUrl)

            AddItem(URL.AbsoluteUri,gethtml(URL))

        Catch ex As Exception
            debug.Print("Error " &amp; ex.StackTrace )
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        btnStart.Enabled =False
        ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50)
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
        listView1.Items.Clear

        For Each sItem As String In txturls.Lines
            if sItem.Trim &lt;&gt;string.empty

                If sItem.Contains("http://")=False Then
                    sItem="http://" &amp; sItem
                End If

                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(New WaitCallback(AddressOf DoWork), sItem)
                TotalItems+=1
                tsslTotal.Text =String.Format ("Total Tasks: {0}",TotalItems)

            end if
        Next

    End Sub
```

thanks

EDIT

for those who asked,

GetHtml gets the web page source from the Internet

AddItem adds the result if the GetHtml to Listview

thanks again for looking

EDIT

i use a this code to check the number of runing threads each second

```
Sub Timer1Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        tsslthreads.Text=string.Format ("Threads: {0}", Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads.Count)
    End Sub
```

thanks

Comment: What does "gethtml" do?  These are probably native threads, not managed by the TP.

Comment: I have updated my post, pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrote a small demo project. Try this code to check for **available** Threads and you will see, that there are only 50 threads **RUNNING**. compare: Your code will **queue** 10000 threads

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int workerThreads = 0;
        int completionPortThreads = 0;
        ThreadPool.GetAvailableThreads(out workerThreads, out completionPortThreads);

        lblTotal.Text = string.Format("Worker {0}/Completion {1}", workerThreads, completionPortThreads);
    }
```

My code is in c# and I had a timer added for showing the number of threads ..

hth

Comment: i have 10,000 queued task, not threads ruining, but 200+ threads runing

Comment: the number of threads in the currentProcess is not the same as in the threadpool. Did you check the number of available process in threadPool with my piece of code? what's the result with my source?

Comment: when i first start the app without starting any work, it shows `Worker 250/Completion 1000`.

Comment: ok -  and after clicking the start button the counter starts at which value? it should bei 50 and count towards zero ... if it is so - everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50) returns a boolean.

Please check if it's TRUE, if not the Set operation didn't succeed.

Can you debug this application?
If yes, press the "pause" button when there are 200 threads.

Add the threads window - On the Debug menu, point to Windows, and then click Threads.

See what these threads do. Maybe you start new threads somewhere else in your application.

Another thing, if you're using .NET 4.0, I would suggest you to use the **Task Parallel Library** API (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx) instead of direct use of the Thread Pool.

Comment: am using .net 2.0, and when i did this `dim blnResult as Boolean = ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads(50, 50)` the value was true

Answer (score 1):

What exactly is wrong and how did you check it?

Remember that:

- `SetMaxThreads` sets maximum number of pool threads *running* at any given moment, not queued tasks.
- `QueueUserWorkItem` adds a task to the queue but doesn't nessesarilly run it. If there's no unused thread in the pool, the task will just wait. But it will be created and added to `ThreadPool`'s queue.